# How to increase and decrease textfield maxLength

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a `textfield`, where I declare `maxLength: 15`. On `focusleave` event, I am adding some more character(s) like `,` so here I want to increase length of `textfield`.

**My code is:**

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'email',
    fieldLabel: 'Email Address',
    maxLength: 15
    vtype: 'email' // requires value to be a valid email address format,
    listeners: {
        focusleave: function( this, event, eOpts)  {
            var myVAl = this.Value();
            myVAl.toLocaleString({
                minimumFractionDigits: 3
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here, If I put 15 char and then I want decimal after every three character so I am getting only 13 use-full character.

So How to increase and decrease `maxLength` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

> So How to increase and decrease maxLength

Yes, you can change in on [`focusenter`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html#event-focusenter) and [`foucuseleave`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html#event-focusleave) event using [`textfield.inputEl`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html#property-inputEl).

```
textfield.inputEl.dom.maxLength=15//Your dynamic value here
```

In this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2gtf), I have created a demo using same `textfield.inputEl`.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        function stringInsert(str, n, joinwith) {
            var ret = [],
                i = 0,
                len = str.length;;

            for (; i < len; i += n) {
                ret.push(str.substr(i, n))
            }

            return ret.join(joinwith)
        };

        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'form',
            title: 'Demo Form',
            bodyPadding: 15,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'email',
                fieldLabel: 'Email Address',
                vtype: 'email', // requires value to be a valid email address format,
                listeners: {
                    focusenter: function (field) {
                        var value = field.getValue().replace(/\./g, '');
                        field.setValue(value);
                        field.inputEl.dom.maxLength=15;
                    },
                    focusleave: function (field, event, eOpts) {
                        var value = this.getValue(),
                            newValue = stringInsert(value, 3, '.');

                        field.inputEl.dom.maxLength=newValue.length;
                        field.setValue(newValue);
                    }
                }
            }]
        })
    }
});
```